# Не работает домашняя сеть на ноутбуке

Tags: windows-10, wifi

На ноутбуке dell latitude e7450 не работает домашняя сеть. Подключается потом отключается и пишет "Подключеон без доступа в интернет" Или же если подключено то всё равно не работает. И самое главное, если раздавать с телефона, то работает всё нормально. С вай-фаем проблем нету, ибо есть ещё 2 ноутбука и компьютер, там всё работает. Драйвера так же обновлены

Comment: С телефоном он по проводу соединяется, когда в интернет выходит, а с домашним рутером по wifi?

Comment: Нет, всё по вай фаю

Comment: Тогда неверна начальная постановка задачи "Не работает вай фай на ноутбуке". Моё заключение: "wifi работает". Исправлена постановка в тексте.

Comment: Домашняя сеть на ноутбуке не работает, как я и написал.

Comment: Заголовок был "Не работает вай фай на ноутбуке" (я исправил). Я по нему зашел, а по факту - другая проблема. По ней не подскажу, а совет по wifi вам не нужен.

Comment: На всякий случай: рутер, конечно, перегрузить надо по питанию, лучше вообще шнур питания секунд на 30 вытащив. Он может и один ноут невзлюбить. У меня такое лечится либо перезагрузкой ноута (сетевая карта глючит) или рутера.  + Проверьте, что вы с конфигурациями рутера не играли и ноут не прописали в каких-нибудь черных списках. Полагаю, сам ноут вы уже не раз по питаною перегрузили.

Comment: Та не, уже всё перепробовал, так с любой вай фай сетью, кроме раздачи через телефон, что удивительно..

Comment: Тогда может и wifi. 1) рядом с рутером ставили ноут? (чтобы уровень сигнала гарантировать) ) 2) 5ГГц есть на ноуте и рутере? - не помогает переход на него? 3) по проводу пытались соединить с рутером? 4) можно ещё поставить что-то типа inSSIDER и сравнить показания по Wifi при связи с телефоном и с рутером (уровни сигнала, занимаемые wifi каналы, 2.4 ГГц против 5 ГГц).

Comment: Уже разобрался, не знаю как, не знаю почему, но помогла переустановка биос.